# Spark data frame actions for selected rows

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark

I have a data frame like below

```
  +------++-----------------------+
  | state|     time stamp         |
  +------+------------------------+
  |  0   |  Sun Aug 13 10:58:44   |
  |  1   |  Sun Aug 13 11:59:44   |
  |  1   |  Sun Aug 13 12:50:43   |
  |  1   |  Sun Aug 13 13:00:44   |
  |  0   |  Sun Aug 13 13:58:42   |
  |  0   |  Sun Aug 13 14:00:41   |
  |  0   |  Sun Aug 13 14:30:45   |
  |  0   |  Sun Aug 13 14:58:46   |
  |  1   |  Sun Aug 13 15:00:47   |
  |  0+  |  Sun Aug 13 16:00:49   |
  +------+------------------------+
```

I need to select the timestamps only when state changes from 1 to 0,

I need to separate these rows separately

```
  Sun Aug 13 11:59:44 

  Sun Aug 13 13:58:42

  Sun Aug 13 15:00:47

  Sun Aug 13 16:00:49
```

then take the time differences and sum up.

So can some one suggest, what kind of query I should write for this .

I need some result like below

```
(13:58:42 - 11:59:44) + (16:00:49 - 15:00:47)
```

Comment: 3 x "I need" and 0 x "I've tried"

Comment: @indra : what you have tried so far... and what is failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Window` function should help with your first need. `Filter` will fulfill you third need. Your third need can be fulfilled by extracting the `time` from the date-time value.

Given a dataframe as

```
+-----+-------------------+
|state|timestamp          |
+-----+-------------------+
|0    |Sun Aug 13 10:58:44|
|1    |Sun Aug 13 11:59:44|
|1    |Sun Aug 13 12:50:43|
|1    |Sun Aug 13 13:00:44|
|0    |Sun Aug 13 13:58:42|
|0    |Sun Aug 13 14:00:41|
|0    |Sun Aug 13 14:30:45|
|0    |Sun Aug 13 14:58:46|
|1    |Sun Aug 13 15:00:47|
|0    |Sun Aug 13 16:00:49|
+-----+-------------------+
```

Doing the things I explained above should help. Doing the following should solve your first and second needs.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("temp", lag("state", 1).over(Window.orderBy("timestamp")))
    .withColumn("temp", when(col("temp").isNull, lit(0)).otherwise(col("temp")))
    .filter(col("state") =!= col("temp"))
```

You should have

```
+-----+-------------------+----+
|state|timestamp          |temp|
+-----+-------------------+----+
|1    |Sun Aug 13 11:59:44|0   |
|0    |Sun Aug 13 13:58:42|1   |
|1    |Sun Aug 13 15:00:47|0   |
|0    |Sun Aug 13 16:00:49|1   |
+-----+-------------------+----+
```

Now regarding you third need, you need to find ways to extract `time` from `timestamp` column and do something like below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("temp", lag("state", 1).over(Window.orderBy("timestamp")))
    .withColumn("temp", when(col("temp").isNull, lit(0)).otherwise(col("temp")))
    .filter(col("state") =!= col("temp"))
    .select(collect_list(col("timestamp")).as("time"))
    .withColumn("time", concat_ws(" + ", concat_ws(" - ", $"time"(1), $"time"(0)), concat_ws(" - ", $"time"(3), $"time"(2))))
```

You should have

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|time                                                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Sun Aug 13 13:58:42 - Sun Aug 13 11:59:44 + Sun Aug 13 16:00:49 - Sun Aug 13 15:00:47|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful except with extraction of `time` value from `timestamp` column